# Contenido desplegable android

Tags: android, android-studio, programación-móvil

Como puedo hacer en android un contenido desplegable,  es decir tengo dos botones al presionar el primero,  en medio de estos me aparezcan imagenes o texto,la idea no es poner el text view o el image view invisible porque aun asi queda el contenido, quiero que los botones esten pegados y en medio aparesca el contenido al presionarlo, es decir que se pueda rellene sin que antes quedara ese espacio en blanco,algo como la respuesta a este comentario http://www.forosdelweb.com/f13/contenido-desplegable-717815/,  en android studio

Comment: Has intentado algo, puedes iniciar con botones que tengan un listener, al dar click aparezca o desaparezca la vista mediante el metodo setVisibility(); https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Comment: Pero quedaria el espacio, de los textview, no quiero que quede ese espacio, si no que inicialmente tenga solo dos botones pegados y en medio al presioanr el primero se pueda ver el contenido

Comment: para "eliminar" ese espacio, puedes usar setVisisbility(View.GONE); con esto la vista se hace invisible y el espacio también desaparece.

Comment: Usted tiene toda la razón la propiedad es (View.GONE), muchisimas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenidas, trata de realizar tu proyecto y ya teniendo código si tienes problemas puedes preguntar, cuando preguntes trata de ser especifico y aportar más datos para que no te cierren la pregunta =(, Saludos Fdy!